# How to write an incremental loop in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a method that each time it is called I want to increment the counter and display that number beside my hello world (i have denoted the # sign as my number), I am not sure how to go about doing this in xslt.

```
<a onclick="clicker(this)"><img src="tab.gif" />
    hello world #
</a>
```

For example say my method is called 3 times I would have

hello world 1
hello world 2
hello world 3

and if my method is called only once I would have just

hello world

(no number if just called once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged as XSLT 2.0 where you can do e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 3">
  <a onclick="clicker(this)"><img src="tab.gif"/>
    hello world <xsl:value-of select="if (last() gt 1) then . else ()"/>
  </a>
</xsl:for-each>
```

With XSLT 1.0 if you have a template

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <a onclick="clicker(this)"><img src="tab.gif"/>
    hello world <xsl:if test="last() > 1"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:if>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

you could use `<xsl:apply-templates select="//foo"/>`. But you would better show us the code you have that you call a `method` in XSLT, then it is hopefully clearer what you have and how you want to use it.

Comment: my apologies, it seems that I am not running xslt-2.0, and I cannot do the "1 to 3" is there a change I can make to run this?

Comment: I have added an XSLT 1.0 sample that might help, if not, post the code you have and consider a `method`.